# Cannot get validation to work with Spring boot and Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-validator

I'm working with Spring boot and Thymeleaf,and I have problem with showing validation errors. This is how my model looks.

```
@Size(min = 1, message = "Address is invalid.")
@NotNull
@Column
private String address;
```

My controller looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
public String createNewBusiness(@Valid @ModelAttribute("business") Business business, BindingResult result, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("userEmail", getUserEmail());
    logger.info("/business/create:" + business.toString());
    LocationResponse locationResponse = geoService.getCoords(business.getAddress());

    if(locationResponse.getStatus().equals("OK")) {
        business.setLatitude(locationResponse.getResults().get(0).getGeometry().getLocation().getLat());
        business.setLongitude(locationResponse.getResults().get(0).getGeometry().getLocation().getLng());
        business.setUserId(getUserId());

        businessService.createNew(business);

        model.addAttribute("business", business);

    }else{
        business.setAddress(null);
        model.addAttribute("business", business);

    }

    if(result.hasErrors()){
        List<FieldError> errors = result.getFieldErrors();
        for (FieldError error : errors ) {
            System.out.println (error.getObjectName() + " - " + error.getDefaultMessage());
        }
        return "newBusiness";
    }

    return "business";
}
```

And Thymeleaf looks like this:

```
<div class="input-field left m-0 w-100">
                            <i class="fa fa-map-marker prefix grey-text" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            <input placeholder="Address" id="inputAddress" name="address" type="text" class="validate my-0" th:required="true">
                            <label th:errors="*{address}" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('address')}" >Invalid address </label>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Please provide more information: What exactly is the problem? Can you provide sample output? Is the validation not running, or is it something else? What does your data look like? Where or when does the "problem" happen? Please show all of the code that contains  `private String address`.

Comment: `th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('address')}"` is redundant. `th:errors` only render the element if there are errors.